# activity do android studio não abre com botão click

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Meu problema é o seguinte. meu aplicativo possui uma tela de boas-vindas onde o usuário ckick o botão "continuar" e vai para a próxima tela. O próximo contém um menu com vários botões. meu problema é que não consigo abrir outra activity na segunda tela (na primeira tela que abre normal) mais ou menos este esquema abaixo (| activity1> botão continua | >> | activity2> botão continue2 |> não responde |tela3>> nao abre) para elogie e teste o apk em um galaxy grand duos 4.2.2

código abaixo 
 tela do código 1 (bem-vindo).

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
Button button7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);

button7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main4);
    }
});}}
```

codigo tela 2

```
public class Main4Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
private  Button prova;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main4);

prova = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);

    prova.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent( Main4Activity.this, 
    Main3Activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});

}}
```

tela 2 codigo xml butao

```
            <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
            android:text="tela 2"/>
```

[image: anexo imagem]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá,

O problema do seu App está no método `onClick` da primeira `Activity`, quando você executa o método `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main4);` você está apenas carregando o layout da tela, e não passando o controle do processamento para a próxima `activity`, então o método `onClick` do `prova.setOnClickListener` não é executado. Para corrigir o erro, crie uma `Intent` para chamar a `Main4Activity`. Substitua o trecho:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main4);
```

por:

```
Intent intentProva = new Intent( Main2Activity.this, 
Main4Activity.class);
    startActivity(intentProva);
```

Comment: muito bom, funcionou perfeitamente. obrigado!!!